# How can I make my delete button work?

Tags: sql, ajax, forms, mysqli

Please excuse me for being a noob when it comes to what is probably not that hard....

I am writing a page which has a table which allows users to add players into a game. Every `<td>` contains a `<input type='hidden'...` and a piece of information (player name, place, points etc). There is also a 'delete' button (for use when a player is mistakenly added twice, or the wrong player is added to the list). At this stage, when clicking save, the table submits all the hidden inputs to the "Confirm results" page before closing the page and updating the database.

The problem I am having is that the players need to be added to and deleted from the database live. To do this, I've created a form will post their details to the same page, then if (I'm paraphrasing here) `if($form = 'new player')` an SQL command will add a temp file to the database to show that player is registered, then an `SQL SELECT` will get all the players in that game and echo them to the page. I want the delete button to delete the players row from the database the moment it is clicked and refresh the page, but the only way I know to do this is with a form, and this would create a form within a form.

How else can I make the delete button remove a row from a database without leaving the current window and without using another form? Is this something that should be done with AJAX? (I know almost nothing about AJAX - learning it is next on my to do list, but right now I just want to get this page to work).

added: One idea I had was to make the delete button more like a `msgbox` to create an inner window that basically says "Are you sure you want to delete John Smith" and then run the SQL code in that window. Would something like that work? How can I do that?

Comment: Definitely. Use ajax. Do you have a primary key or some unique identifier for each row in your `players` table ?

Comment: I do. Each player on the `players` table has an ID. Each row in the table has an ID which is the word player followed by that players ID

Answer (score 1):

You can call an action from a buton click via AJAX.
So if you have an action set up to do what you want (your delete) then you should be abkle to fire it.....

I use MVC razor and do it like this....
JQuery....

```
$("#yourButton").click(function (e) {
  var url = "@Url.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName")";
  //alert(url);
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: { param1: param1Val, param2: param2Val },
      success: function (result) {
          ..Do something with result if required
      }                
  });
  return true;
});
```

I've had similar scenarios to you and I am pretty new to this also, however, this seems to work nicely.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hmm... I just upvoted your answer because I get part of it, but I'm still a bit confused... I think at this stage I will let the delete button be a checkbox so the deleting happens later and I'll learn more about AJAX and come back to this one.

Comment: Thanks.
I am working on something similar at the moment.
I have a model which has a list in it.
The items in the list have a property to say if they were added, update, deleted or unchanged.
Via a JQuery click event I set this property and hide items flagged for deleteing.  Then when I come to save my model, i check this property and perform the appropriate operation.

When I add to the list, I call an action which returns a partial view (which is a a table row) which I then append to the main table.

I've got it working nicely now.  I can post.